# want to pass structure array from perl script to cpp file

Tags: c++, perl

I want to parse one text file and get 3 parameters values out of it. I want to store this data in structure array and pass this structure array to one cpp file. What kind of data structure should I use in perl and how should I collect that structure array in cpp file?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat unclear. Do you want the Perl program to generate *source code* that goes into a .cpp file before compilation, or do you want to read the output of a Perl program from a running C++ program?

Perl has a single array type, so you would use that for both cases.

If you are just using Perl to generate code, have it write a code fragment to a file using plain print statements, then #include that in your C++ source.

If you want to read the output of a Perl script from a running C++ program, and it is simple values that do not contain spaces or otherwise need escaping, you can simply use popen(3) to launch the script and fscanf(3) to read its output; then have the Perl script just output in a fscanf-compatible format with e.g. `print "@result";`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, popen solved my problem. I was thinking to get the parameter values from perl by using SV*, which I felt complicated. But this popen and fscanf made my life simple :)